# Что такое .col-sm в Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

вроде бы разобрался с классами .col и .offset , но не пойму .col-sm, как написано по английский , если я правильно перевёл, это сброс .offset

> In addition to column clearing at responsive breakpoints, you may need to reset offsets.

, но тогда пример вообще не понятен

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">.col-sm-5 .col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-0">.col-sm-5 .offset-sm-2 .col-md-6 .offset-md-0</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">.col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 offset-md-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-0">.col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .offset-md-2 .col-lg-6 .offset-lg-0</div>
</div>
```

вот его результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для адаптации под устройства >= 576px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `col-sm-*` означает количество колонок на экранах шириной ≥ 576px. Непосредственно к `offset` он не имеет отношения: отступ можно добавить на любых размерах экрана.

А вообще, прежде чем верстать на бутстрапе, как следует изучите [документацию на русском](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) - там всё подробно и понятно описано.

Comment: я просто смотрел видеокурс от Ивана Петриченко, он говорил, что не стоит читать на русском документацию, она неправильная и не понятная. Лучше читайте в оригинале. Да и я для себя пытаюсь тоже на англйиском читать, потому что это жизненно важный навык для разработчика, понимать на английском документалку. Но как видите, не понимаю

Comment: @РусланКамов, не знаю, кто такой Иван Петриченко, но документация по Бустрапу переведена на русский вполне адекватно. Чтобы читать и разбираться по-английски, надо хорошо знать язык. Если Вы им не вполне владеете, то не стоит тратить силы и время - изучайте по-русски.

Comment: Я с Вами не спорю, но очень многих видел разработчиков, которые плохо знали английский в повседневной жизни, обычные слова, но бегло читали документацию, натренировав этот набор слов под неё. Поэтому и сам пытался